# Need bios boot instead of boot menu

Tags: boot, bios, dualboot

I want to do like that I install 2 os on 2 partition on a same SSD and then I want that if I turn on my pc it should automatically boot to windows but when I want I can go to bios boot menu and select a different os and then if I restart it should again boot to windows can I do that ? or can I select from windows only to boot to another os and then restart to go back to windows ?

Comment: You can only expect the last change to be kept. But with UEFI you can set "Windows bootloader manager" that will always boot Windows directly and then use the one-time boot menu or the boot override feature in UEFI ("BIOS") to have a one.time boot to another OS.

Comment: if everything is setup properly, you should be able to hit F12 (or whatever button your firmware uses; I've also seen F8) during boot to select which volume you want to boot off of. you will need GPT partitions to support bootable volumes, and probably need to be using a UEFI bios.

Answer (score -1):

To boot into BIOS press your systems Boot Key, which is normally displayed on startup. If not, refer to your manual. (It's usually F12, ESC, DEL, VolDown, or Enter.) You should be able to Boot into your BIOS or Quick Boot Menu.

**From BIOS:**
Select the volume you want to boot in the `Boot` section, then you can advance to that partition's bootloader.

**From Quick Start:**
You should be able to find a volume in your Quick Start menu to easily boot to.

**If one of these is a Linux Distro booting with GRUB:**
You can set the default bootloader to GRUB Boot Menu, where you can select between what OS you want to boot to each time you boot up. Follow the guide [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/923136/how-to-set-grub-as-the-boot-manager).